# Database can't Open, error : java.lang.NullPointerExecption

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

at this time I want to ask, I got an error when I try to read my data from database, in Validation activity, The Error is Sign Below.

Validation.java

```
public class Validation extends Activity{

private static DBDataSource dataSource; 


// Error Messages
private static final String REQUIRED_MSG = "required";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
    dataSource.open();
}
//this method is to check is my textbox empty or not, the i want to modified to check is my textbox empty or equals data from database
public static boolean hasText(EditText editText) {

    ArrayList<Sma> list = dataSource.getAllSma(); >> when i add this code, the apps currently stop, and the got error message java.lang.NullPointer Exception
    String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    editText.setError(null);

    // length 0 means there is no text
    if (text.length() == 0) {
        editText.setError(REQUIRED_MSG);
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

and here is my DBDataSource

```
 public ArrayList<Sma> getAllSma() 
 {
    ArrayList<Sma> daftarSma = new ArrayList<Sma>();

    // select all SQL query
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);


    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
    {
      Sma sekolah = cursorToSma(cursor);
      daftarSma.add(sekolah);
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
    return daftarSma;
  }
```

can anyone help me figured this out about this error, cause i really don't know why this is happend. Thank you :D

and here when i call validation Activity

```
 public class CreateData extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 private Validation valid;
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_data);
  edNama_sma        = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nama_sma);
  registerViews();
  }

 private void registerViews() {

        edNama_sma.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                valid.hasText(edNama_sma);
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
        });
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {}
```

my Error

```
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565): java.lang.NullPointerException
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at      com.example.validation.search.Validation.hasText(Validation.java:76)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at com.example.search.CreateData$5.afterTextChanged(CreateData.java:230)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7259)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:8915)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:970)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:497)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:435)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:672)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:435)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:333)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
 04-05 13:54:00.727: E/AndroidRuntime(27565):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post some stacktrace. Likely `datasource` is not initialized when you call the method in a static way.

Comment: @laalto : i already post it, can you help me out?

Comment: Well, how are you instantiating your `Validation` activity?

Comment: @ndr_sd mostly your edittext object is null

Comment: @laalto : i already post my Activity, can you check it?

Comment: @kalyanpvs: i don't think so, cause i already check myEditText :D

Comment: @ndr_sd ok..so you need to post complete validation class code..

Answer (score 1):

The activity `Validation` has not been initialized and its `onCreate()` has not been called. Hence `datasource` is `null` and you get NPE.

From what you've posted, `Validation` should not be an activity at all. You should only extend `Activity` for classes that are actual activities, listed in manifest and instantiated via an `Intent`.

For methods that require a valid `Context` such as `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor, pass it as an argument instead of trying to use `this` of a non-instantiated `Activity`.

Comment: instantiate via an intent? do you mean i should call the validation activity?

Comment: No, I mean validation should not be an activity since you don't invoke it via an intent.

Comment: okay, it's mean that i should Context when i need to access dataSource right? can you give some example? cause i'm really newbie in programming :D